Windows 11 on Gigabyte hardware hangs or freezes sometimes with blues screen for no reason
Since few weeks the licensed Windows 11 started hanging and freezing all the time when I'm playing games. The PC just stops responding, sometimes it shows a blue death screen. The PC was assembled about two years ago and has latest, stable, modern specs. There are no critical errors in the Windows EventLogs. After each hung a hard reset is required. Please, help me as I can't play my favourite games. How can I diagnose this problem? The Windows EventLog does not contain useful information, related to the subject.
This happens all the time now. Here is a blue screen:

The PC completely freezes and it requires a hard power off and power on after that.
This only happens when I'm playing games. At a random point in time, PC can work for an hour and after that it happens, sometimes it is immediate when I'm starting a game.
There is no minidump file created.
There are no meaningful errors in the Windows Event Log.
I'm 100% sure that there are no viruses on my PC. I've scanned my PC using most powerful anti-viruses and using Microsoft (Windows Security) protection all the time.
Something very bad happens as my PC freesez completely, it can't produce the minidump or execute any other commands. It just hangs and stucks completely.
I have all the latest drivers installed. There are no missing or conflicting devices/drivers, everything seems to be good.
Here are some warnings from the Windows Event Log that I've got:
Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Hypervisor
The hypervisor did not enable mitigations for side channel vulnerabilities for virtual machines because HyperThreading is enabled. To enable mitigations for virtual machines, disable HyperThreading.

another warning:
Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig
WLAN Extensibility Module has stopped.
Module Path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\netwtw6e.inf_amd64_bf4689a7153fc9c5\IntelIHVRouter14.dll

and one more:
aqnic650 Marvell AQtion 10GBASE-T Network Adapter
Marvell AQtion 10GBASE-T Network Adapter : Network link is lost.

From the forums, I read that this might be cause by the anti-cheat software.
I see some very suspicious services running on my PC - names are ending with some random salt:

AarSvc_1fc717 (Agent Activation Runtime_1fc717)
BluetoothUserService_1fc717 (Bluetooth User Support Service_1fc717)
CaptureService_1fc717 cbdhsvc_1fc717 (Clipboard User Service_1fc717)
CloudBackupRestoreSvc_1fc717 (Cloud Backup and Restore
Service_1fc717) CDPUserSvc_1fc717 (Connected Devices Platform User
Service_1fc717) ConsentUxUserSvc_1fc717 (ConsentUX User
Service_1fc717) PimIndexMaintenanceSvc_1fc717 (Contact Data_1fc717)
......

there are dozens of them and I'm not sure what are they for.
UPDATE 1: the PC crashes only when CPU is highly loaded. For example, I can use the PC for hours with low performant tasks, watching videos etc. As soon as I load the CPU heavily, it immediately crashes. For example, when I start the CINEBENCH performance load test tool - it immediately crashes.
UPDATE 2: During the Windows Memory Diagnostics run no errors were detected, that means the RAM memory is completely fine.
UPDATE 3: recently, I've updated the BIOS version to the latest one - that might be the cause. However not 100% sure
UPDATE 4: it appears that the CPU is damaged. I've tried several CPU load and stress tools - all of them fail. The CPU stress tests doesn't pass. The only possible solution - is to replace the CPU
PC specs are as follows:

OS: Windows 11 (licensed), all mandatory latest updates are applied
CPU: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900KS, Socket 1700 LGA (0x1)
Chipset
Northbridge: Intel Alder Lake rev. 02
Southbridge: Intel Z690 rev. 11
Bus Specification: PCI-Express 5.0 (32.0 GT/s)
Graphic Interface: PCI-Express
Memory Type: DDR5
Memory Size: 32 GBytes
Channels: 4 x 32-bit
Memory Frequency: 3200.0 MHz (1:32)
Memory Max Frequency: 3200.0 MHz
CAS# latency (CL): 32.0
RAS# to CAS# delay (tRCD): 39
RAS# Precharge (tRP): 39
Cycle Time (tRAS): 80
Bank Cycle Time (tRC): 119
Row Refresh Cycle Time (tRFC): 510
Command Rate (CR): 2T
Uncore Frequency: 3600.0 MHz
Memory Controller Frequency: 1600.0 MHz
Host Bridge: 0x4660
Motherboard:
manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd.
product: Z690 AORUS MASTER


Just a comment to start things: Windows doesn't Blue Screen for "no reason". The most common reason for BSODs are drivers. So, have you checked for and installed the latest available drivers and firmware for all of your computer's components? Next, BSODs always have a message on them: What is the message your BSODs showing you? Is it always the same, or does it change?

Re those services: Those are normal Microsoft services and service names. I am not sure what the alphanumeric codes following the names mean, but that's something that's been used since at least Windows 10. Hard freezes without any dump indicate to me a severe hardware fault, most likely.

it appears that the CPU is damaged. I've tried to boot from a linux bootable USB and tried multiple CPU diagnostics tools - it DOES NOT pass. There are multiple errors thrown when diagnosing the CPU. It's been almos three years since this PC was assembled. Three years is a lot for the PC hardware, there are modern CPUs and Motherboards. I've  decided to upgrade my PC as CPU is not recoverable unit.

Sounds like you found it. 3 years isn't at all a long time for CPU though. It COULD be simply an age fault, but I would also be more careful regarding the cooling (the primary cause of home-built PC CPU damage) going forward.
